# Is there a zoom and timer functionality on Nexus S camera?

Tags: camera, samsung-nexus-s, zooming

If not, is there another app that gives this functionality?

Comment: I don't think that any of the Android phones on the market at the moment (including the Nexus S) have a proper optical zoom, so the best you're going to get is a digital zoom that you could just do yourself in Photoshop later.

Comment: What GAThrawn said - digital zoom is essentially the same as cropping the image afterwards which you can do within the standard gallery app after taking your picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no timer built in, but you can crop images in the standard gallery app which is essentially the same as digital zoom.

There are a number of apps which list timer functionality (I haven't tried them myself so can't verify first hand how well they work):

- [Vignette](https://market.android.com/details?id=uk.co.neilandtheresa.NewVignette&feature=search_result)
- [Camera ZOOM FX](https://market.android.com/details?id=slide.cameraZoom&feature=search_result) ~ also lists zoom and "clap to snap" features
- [Camera Self-Timer](https://market.android.com/details?id=identity.android.CameraSelfTimer&feature=search_result)
- [Camera Advance Lite](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mnapps.cameraadvancelite&feature=search_result)

Plus [a load of others](https://market.android.com/search?q=camera+timer&c=apps).

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely zoom.  I don't believe there's a timer, but an app like [PRO Zoom Camera 5x](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.popularcrowd.piczoompro) should work for that (note, it doesn't say whether it works for the NS).  Additionally, you could use an app like [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to time the shot; [its website](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/tour.html) mentions that specifically.