# Camera time delay on 2.3.5?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a zoom and timer functionality on Nexus S camera?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7064/is-there-a-zoom-and-timer-functionality-on-nexus-s-camera)

Is there any app that will let one use a time-delay shot with the phone's camera on Android 2.3.5? The default camera app doesn't seem to have time-delay shots, as far as I can see.

Comment: This previous question has some options for setting a delay on the camera before the picture's taken: [Is there a zoom and timer functionality on Nexus S camera?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7064/)

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try this one: https://market.android.com/details?id=identity.android.CameraSelfTimer&feature=search_result&rdid=identity.android.CameraSelfTimer&rdot=1

Comment: "Is there an app for X?" questions are [off-topic on Android
Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq). You should
rephrase the question to ask for a solution to a problem you are
facing or a task you want to achieve (e.g. simply without mentioning
that an app may be the solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one does the trick pretty well:
https://market.android.com/details?id=identity.android.CameraSelfTimer&feature=search_result&rdid=identity.android.CameraSelfTimer&rdot=1